# Azure AKS use insecure docker registry

Tags: azure, kubernetes, nexus, azure-aks, azure-cli

I have a private Nexus installed inside Azure cluster and want to get container images from that Nexus for all Kubernetes deployments.

But on the initial step of development Nexus isn't configured over https and Kubernetes throws an error:

```
Failed to pull image "<nexusname>.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8082/<image>:1.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "<nexusname>.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8082/<image>:1.0": failed to resolve reference "<nexusname>.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8082/<image>:1.0": failed to do request: Head https://<nexusname>.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8082/v2/<image>/manifests/1.0: dial tcp <ip>:443: i/o timeout
```

Locally I can configure insecure-registry url and it works, like this

```
{
    “insecure-registries”: ["<nexusname>.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8082"]
}
```

Is there a way to enable this on Azure Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure insecure registry setting on every node in your cluster. Depends on your container runtime (docker vs containerd), the steps are different:

**Docker**:

1. Stop docker service: `sudo systemctl stop docker`
2. Edit `/etc/default/docker.json` on every node:

   ```
    {
        “insecure-registries”: ["<nexusname>.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8082"]
    }
   ```
3. Start docker service: `sudo systemctl start docker`

**containerd:**

1. Stop containerd service: `sudo systemctl stop containerd`
2. Edit `/etc/containerd/config.toml` on every node:

   ```
   [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
     [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
       [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."<nexusname>.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8082"]
         endpoint = ["http://<nexusname>.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8082"]
     [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]
       [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."<nexusname>.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8082".tls]
         insecure_skip_verify = true
   ```
3. Start containerd service: `sudo systemctl start containerd`

Source:

- [How to configure a kubernetes cluster to use a local (insecure) registry](https://wiki.onap.org/display/DW/questions/38118463/how-to-configure-a-kubernetes-cluster-to-use-a-local-insecure-registry)
- [Configure Registry TLS Communication](https://github.com/containerd/cri/blob/master/docs/registry.md#configure-registry-tls-communication)

Comment: yes, I know it. but how to do it on Azure kubernetes cluster in safe way? with azure cli maybe

Comment: Hi @OLA, Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible.